# TFS Build definition - include external files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

How can I split a TFS build definition in few files?

Specific: I have a lot of `XmlUpdate` definitions in `<Target Name="AfterCompile">` section. So I would like to allocate them in separated files and include this file in the main `proj` one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using the upgrade template and talking about TFSBuild.proj file? Yes, you can include any file using the  tag. You would have to have the file already present on the build server and not include it in the 
external file in the workspace.

Comment: I can be wrong, but all files located in the same folder as the Build Templare gets downloaded, so you do not need copying them manually on the build server

Comment: @Hamid-Shahid Yes, I'm using upgrade template. Which tag do you mean? I tried with `import` but without success.
Could you paste the code

Comment: Which version of TFS are you on? If >= 2010 you should change your build template to start using either the XAML templates and if you are on 2013, then create from pre and post PowerShell scripts to do your xmlUpate.  For 2010 and 2012 you can update the XAML template to do what you want in the XAML directly instead.